# Html element with a not immediate child with a specific id

Tags: scripting, dojo

I am using dojo and I want to get a node that has a not immediate child, and this child has an specific id. How can I do this using dojo.query? I want to get this node to hide it.

Comment: This could use some clarification - I think I'd misread this question when I first looked at it.  Are you saying you want to get at the ancestor based on the descendant?  Also, is there anything special about the ancestor that would help identify it?  (e.g. does it have a particular class, or is it the first of a particular tag found tracing up from the child?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using dojo.isDescendant. If ancestor tag has a className "class" and descendant has an Id "Id":

des = dojo.byId("Id");
dojo.query(". 'class'").forEach(function(node) { 
                                   if(dojo.isDescendant(des, node) { 
                                   //something
                                   }});

Answer (score 0):

For reference [Look here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/query.html).

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"><span>HIDE ME</span> some other text</div>
```

Here's the query syntax:
All  elements that are immediate children of node with id="myDiv"
dojo.query('#myDiv > span')

```
 dojo.query('#myDiv > span').forEach(function(node, index, arr){
node.style("display", "none");      
  });
```